# how to store store (an array of) unsigned bytes in Java to do bit manipulations on them?

Tags: java

I need to store (an array of) unsigned bytes in Java to do bit manipulations on them. 
I want to do standard bit manipulations. shift `((sVal>>8) & 0xff);`, or |, and &, and comparisons. and things like `w |= ~0xff;`
How do I store them?

byte b =  0x96; //the value is 150

I get a compile error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte

so I cast it

byte b = (cast) 0x96;

Now I see the value has changed to -106.

If I store as a char, that will promote it to 2 bytes.

How should I store the value as an unsigned byte in Java so that I can do bit manipulations on them?

Will there be issues using **int**?

Comment: The storing can be anything, since you can do bit manipulation operations on any type of number. It shouldnt matter since at the end of the day its still 0's and 1's (just omit the actual value and focus on where the 0's and 1's are), and if you want to find out the result, just call the toBinaryString() methods, or implement your own getBit() and setBit() methods which are pretty straight forward.

Comment: `char` is unsigned, and will act like any other integer if you treat it as one.  It is, of course, 16 bits, so you'd have to mask the high half in some cases.  Or you can use `short` or `int` and simply never do anything that causes the high-order bit to be set.

Comment: You need to understand binary data representation, and that 0x96 *is* -106 in a signed byte.

Comment: @HotLicks I did understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem using bit operations (apart from unsigned-shift-right) if you are not doing sign involving arithmetics.

Yes, converting to char or int extends the sign, but you can do:

```
byte b = (byte)0x96;
int n = 0xFF & b; // Again 0..255
```

(Maybe one should warn, trying to store bytes in a String with chars, is a kind of abuse involving encoding conversion.)

By the way, the classes [Integer, Long and such](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros%28int%29) have many interesting bit operations. The class BitSet is also an interesting playground.

Comment: but I am going to also do comparisons. and things like `w |= ~0xff;`

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I am going to do right-shift and comparisons also

Comment: `|= ~0xff` would work. `>>/>>>` are problematic. Using short means alway resetting the high byte, `&= 0xFF`. So probably short + reset is the best choice. _What about **BitSet**? Especially as you mentioned array of byte._

Comment: having a BitSet instance for each byte does not seem efficient in space. What about using int + reset?

Comment: int + reset is fine too, and in fact the JVM uses `int` for smaller values. BitSet is more a replacement for an array of byte.

Answer (score 3):

There is no unsigned primitive data type in Java -- bytes are signed.  You'll need to figure out some other way to represent your data, depending on what you want to do.

EDIT:

People have given you a number of suggestions and explanations, and you haven't explained much about the requirements of your situation ('a lot of them and fast' isn't helpful).  But I noticed something else about your original post.

You say

> `byte b = (cast) 0x96;`
>
> Now I see the value has changed to -106.

I'm wondering if you understand that the value of the byte didn't change at all.  The byte is still hexadecimal 96, and you could see that if you printed it out in hexadecimal.  The -106 is merely the decimal number represented by hex 96.

If ALL you want to do is bit manipulation, then you could STILL store it all as bytes.  Only if you also need arithmetic operations -- add, subtract, multiple, divide, greater than, less than -- would you need to worry about the signed nature of the bytes.

Comment: Well, you could do them on integers and mask out the upper-level 3 bytes.  I don't know how many of them there are or how fast or whatever, but that would allow shifting, etc.  You'll just have to deal with the signing part, in Java, I don't know any way around it.  If it were me I'd define the operations I wanted and write methods that would do those on the bytes in the lowest-order 8 bits of integers, and that would allow me to insure I wasn't dealing with a negative integer in the first place, etc., without making the upper-level code too messy.

Comment: It is image graphics and has to be fast and there are a lot of them.

Comment: Actually, `char` is unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

You can do bit manipulations on signed bytes--they produce the same results you'd expect.  The one thing you have to watch for is `>>`; this will fill in the leftmost bits with 1 if the signed byte is negative, but if you use `>>>` (three `>` signs), it will always fill the leftmost bits with 0, which in essence treats it like an unsigned byte even though it's signed.

If you want the integer value of a byte and you want a value from 0 to 255:

```
int value = ((int)yourByte) & 0xFF;
```

Or, in Java 8, you can use [`Byte.toUnsignedInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-).

[Actually, the cast isn't necessary, because `yourByte` and `0xFF` will automatically get promoted to `int` before the `&` is applied.  However, I never remember that rule without looking it up, so the explicit cast is helpful to me.]

If you want to do an ordered comparison of two bytes (or one byte and an integer literal) and treat them as unsigned, you can convert them both to `int` using one of the above methods and compare the `int`s.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I am going to do right-shift and comparisons also. I am wondering whether to simply store as int.

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary operations on bytes with no restrictions, just need to be careful with the right shift, depending on what you are willing to achieve. With `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` you can see what is happening right there, although it is not the best representation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte b1 = (byte) 0x96;
        int i1 = b1 & 0xFF;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i1));
        byte b2 = (byte) (b1 << 1);
        int i2 = b2 & 0xFF;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i2));
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i1 & i2));
    }
```

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I am going to do right-shift and comparisons also. I am wondering whether to simply store as int

Comment: "Store as int" gets into what I alluded to before when I said "depending on what you want to do".  Perhaps I should have said "depending on everything you want to do" -- store them?  are there millions of calculations, with CPU speed an issue?  are there buckets and buckets of them in one structure?  All of these things would go into deciding how you want to represent them.  Good luck with it.  As an aside, you might want to mark the earliest one of these answers that you feel answered your question; it's part of how SO works.